# Microsoft Graph Authentication with MSAL (problem)

Tags: asp.net, .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I've been struggling to successfully get data from microsoft graph, to be more precise, struggling to get valid authentication token. I followed all instructions and code samples from their github but I cannot get it to work. In image below is my code.

**Important fact is that when I hardcode token, which I got from Graph Explorer, it works perfectly...
When I try to get data with token obtained with AuthProvider, I get exception Request_ResourceNotFound.**

App is registered, access is granted (that's why it works with hardcoded token).
NuGet references imported are Microsoft.Graph, Microsoft.Graph.Client, Microsoft.Identity.Client (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet)

If someone can help me with this problem or suggest anything, I would be grateful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was requesting "Me" endpoint, while authenticating as application (not user). Exception message was not clear enough to understand that at first...